# Does authorize_access_token also verify an id token?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, authlib

For retrieving an OAuth / OpenID Connect token, the function `authorize_access_token` is used in the [authlib docs](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/frameworks.html#id1). OAuth providers like Google strongly advise to manually verify these tokens, for example by checking the expiry date.

Where is the documentation on `authorize_access_token`? I can't find anything on the website. Does the function verify the token automatically or do I have to do that myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that the documentation for *authlib* is lite on what the function *authorize_access_token()* does.  There is some indication in the *Web OAuth Client* selection of the documentation, but that section only mentions the return value of *authorize_access_token().*

```
# this only returns a token
token = oauth.providername.authorize_access_token()
```

In order to fully understand the functionality of *authorize_access_token()* we need to explore *authlib’s* GitHub repository.

Here is a section of code from the a *django* client code making an *OAuth 2* request.

```
def authorize_access_token(self, request, **kwargs):
        """Fetch access token in one step.
        :param request: HTTP request instance from Django view.
        :return: A token dict.
        """
        if request.method == 'GET':
            error = request.GET.get('error')
            if error:
                description = request.GET.get('error_description')
                raise OAuthError(error=error, description=description)
            params = {
                'code': request.GET.get('code'),
                'state': request.GET.get('state'),
            }
        else:
            params = {
                'code': request.POST.get('code'),
                'state': request.POST.get('state'),
            }

        state_data = self.framework.get_state_data(request.session, params.get('state'))
        params = self._format_state_params(state_data, params)
        token = self.fetch_access_token(**params, **kwargs)

        if 'id_token' in token and 'nonce' in state_data:
            userinfo = self.parse_id_token(token, nonce=state_data['nonce'])
            token['userinfo'] = userinfo
        return token
```

In the *authorize_access_token()* code above we have this call:

```
error = request.GET.get('error')
```

The call accessing a segment of the *base_client* code.  Which has these verifications:

- MismatchingStateError
- MissingRequestTokenError
- MissingTokenError

One of the sub calls in the *base_client* code is to this:

```
 def _on_update_token(self, token, refresh_token=None, access_token=None):
 raise NotImplementedError()
```

If something isn't right then *authorize_access_token()* will thrown an error:

```
if error:
   description = request.GET.get('error_description')
   raise OAuthError(error=error, description=description)
```

Each of these calls within the *authorize_access_token()* function are also doing various types of checks using the *base_client* code, which is extensive.

```
state_data = self.framework.get_state_data(request.session, params.get('state'))
params = self._format_state_params(state_data, params)
token = self.fetch_access_token(**params, **kwargs)
```

The first call *state_data* calls this function:

```
def get_state_data(self, session, state):
        key = f'_state_{self.name}_{state}'
        if self.cache:
            value = self._get_cache_data(key)
        else:
            value = session.get(key)
        if value:
            return value.get('data')
        return None
```

The second call *params* calls this function:

```
 def _format_state_params(state_data, params):
        if state_data is None:
            raise MismatchingStateError()

        code_verifier = state_data.get('code_verifier')
        if code_verifier:
            params['code_verifier'] = code_verifier

        redirect_uri = state_data.get('redirect_uri')
        if redirect_uri:
            params['redirect_uri'] = redirect_uri
        return params
```

The third call *token* calls this function:

```
def fetch_access_token(self, request_token=None, **kwargs):
        """Fetch access token in one step.
        :param request_token: A previous request token for OAuth 1.
        :param kwargs: Extra parameters to fetch access token.
        :return: A token dict.
        """
        with self._get_oauth_client() as client:
            if request_token is None:
                raise MissingRequestTokenError()
            # merge request token with verifier
            token = {}
            token.update(request_token)
            token.update(kwargs)
            client.token = token
            params = self.access_token_params or {}
            token = client.fetch_access_token(self.access_token_url, **params)
        return token
```

The final call in the *authorize_access_token()* function is to
*parse_id_token*, which call this function in the *base_client* code:

```
async def parse_id_token(self, token, nonce, claims_options=None):
        """Return an instance of UserInfo from token's ``id_token``."""
        claims_params = dict(
            nonce=nonce,
            client_id=self.client_id,
        )
        if 'access_token' in token:
            claims_params['access_token'] = token['access_token']
            claims_cls = CodeIDToken
        else:
            claims_cls = ImplicitIDToken

        metadata = await self.load_server_metadata()
        if claims_options is None and 'issuer' in metadata:
            claims_options = {'iss': {'values': [metadata['issuer']]}}

        alg_values = metadata.get('id_token_signing_alg_values_supported')
        if not alg_values:
            alg_values = ['RS256']

        jwt = JsonWebToken(alg_values)

        jwk_set = await self.fetch_jwk_set()
        try:
            claims = jwt.decode(
                token['id_token'],
                key=JsonWebKey.import_key_set(jwk_set),
                claims_cls=claims_cls,
                claims_options=claims_options,
                claims_params=claims_params,
            )
        except ValueError:
            jwk_set = await self.fetch_jwk_set(force=True)
            claims = jwt.decode(
                token['id_token'],
                key=JsonWebKey.import_key_set(jwk_set),
                claims_cls=claims_cls,
                claims_options=claims_options,
                claims_params=claims_params,
            )

        # https://github.com/lepture/authlib/issues/259
        if claims.get('nonce_supported') is False:
            claims.params['nonce'] = None
        claims.validate(leeway=120)
        return UserInfo(claims)
```

Within all the functions above there are calls to other functions within the *base_client* code.  For instance here is another part of the code that is being accessed from the *authorize_access_token()* function:

```
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import AuthBase
from authlib.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client
from authlib.oauth2.auth import ClientAuth, TokenAuth
from ..base_client import (
    OAuthError,
    InvalidTokenError,
    MissingTokenError,
    UnsupportedTokenTypeError,
)
from .utils import update_session_configure

__all__ = ['OAuth2Session', 'OAuth2Auth']


class OAuth2Auth(AuthBase, TokenAuth):
    """Sign requests for OAuth 2.0, currently only bearer token is supported."""

    def ensure_active_token(self):
        if self.client and not self.client.ensure_active_token(self.token):
            raise InvalidTokenError()

    def __call__(self, req):
        self.ensure_active_token()
        try:
            req.url, req.headers, req.body = self.prepare(
                req.url, req.headers, req.body)
        except KeyError as error:
            description = 'Unsupported token_type: {}'.format(str(error))
            raise UnsupportedTokenTypeError(description=description)
        return req


class OAuth2ClientAuth(AuthBase, ClientAuth):
    """Attaches OAuth Client Authentication to the given Request object.
    """
    def __call__(self, req):
        req.url, req.headers, req.body = self.prepare(
            req.method, req.url, req.headers, req.body
        )
        return req


class OAuth2Session(OAuth2Client, Session):
    """Construct a new OAuth 2 client requests session.
    :param client_id: Client ID, which you get from client registration.
    :param client_secret: Client Secret, which you get from registration.
    :param authorization_endpoint: URL of the authorization server's
        authorization endpoint.
    :param token_endpoint: URL of the authorization server's token endpoint.
    :param token_endpoint_auth_method: client authentication method for
        token endpoint.
    :param revocation_endpoint: URL of the authorization server's OAuth 2.0
        revocation endpoint.
    :param revocation_endpoint_auth_method: client authentication method for
        revocation endpoint.
    :param scope: Scope that you needed to access user resources.
    :param redirect_uri: Redirect URI you registered as callback.
    :param token: A dict of token attributes such as ``access_token``,
        ``token_type`` and ``expires_at``.
    :param token_placement: The place to put token in HTTP request. Available
        values: "header", "body", "uri".
    :param update_token: A function for you to update token. It accept a
        :class:`OAuth2Token` as parameter.
    """
    client_auth_class = OAuth2ClientAuth
    token_auth_class = OAuth2Auth
    SESSION_REQUEST_PARAMS = (
        'allow_redirects', 'timeout', 'cookies', 'files',
        'proxies', 'hooks', 'stream', 'verify', 'cert', 'json'
    )

    def __init__(self, client_id=None, client_secret=None,
                 token_endpoint_auth_method=None,
                 revocation_endpoint_auth_method=None,
                 scope=None, redirect_uri=None,
                 token=None, token_placement='header',
                 update_token=None, **kwargs):

        Session.__init__(self)
        update_session_configure(self, kwargs)

        OAuth2Client.__init__(
            self, session=self,
            client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret,
            token_endpoint_auth_method=token_endpoint_auth_method,
            revocation_endpoint_auth_method=revocation_endpoint_auth_method,
            scope=scope, redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
            token=token, token_placement=token_placement,
            update_token=update_token, **kwargs
        )

    def fetch_access_token(self, url=None, **kwargs):
        """Alias for fetch_token."""
        return self.fetch_token(url, **kwargs)

    def request(self, method, url, withhold_token=False, auth=None, **kwargs):
        """Send request with auto refresh token feature (if available)."""
        if not withhold_token and auth is None:
            if not self.token:
                raise MissingTokenError()
            auth = self.token_auth
        return super(OAuth2Session, self).request(
            method, url, auth=auth, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def handle_error(error_type, error_description):
        raise OAuthError(error_type, error_description)
```

Here are the claims linked to validation:

```
REGISTERED_CLAIMS = ['iss', 'sub', 'aud', 'exp', 'nbf', 'iat', 'jti']

REGISTERED_CLAIMS = [
        'redirect_uris',
        'token_endpoint_auth_method',
        'grant_types',
        'response_types',
        'client_name',
        'client_uri',
        'logo_uri',
        'scope',
        'contacts',
        'tos_uri',
        'policy_uri',
        'jwks_uri',
        'jwks',
        'software_id',
        'software_version',
    ]
```

*At each stage of the OAuth/OpenID process *authlib* is doing multiple checks to validate a token.*

I hope that my answer helps you understand the function *authorize_access_token()* better.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Isn't `update` just a built in function for dictionaries? I'm looking for verification like described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#validatinganidtoken).

Comment: I updated my answer with additional function calls and information.

Answer (score 0):

Authlib [tracks the token expiration](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/169c7dcfc47478c8d55553cc95fb0f5578162b77/authlib/integrations/base_client/framework_integration.py#L43) date [when it acquires the key](https://github.com/lepture/authlib/blob/169c7dcfc47478c8d55553cc95fb0f5578162b77/authlib/integrations/django_client/apps.py) in `authorize_access_token`, but it does not immediately test to see if the key is expired. (It doesn't expect to pull a key which is expired!)